# Django ManytoMany and through

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I have the following models:

```
class Book(models.Model):    
    ASIN = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(FacebookCustomUser, through='BookRatings')

class BookRatings(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(FacebookCustomUser)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    rating = models.IntegerField()
```

Now I want to get all books and ratings for a logged user. I tried the following:

```
books = request.user.book_set.all()
```

But now in books is no field for the rating. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`book_set` gives you the Book record, not the BookRating one. You can get that via the standard reverse relationship:

```
request.user.bookratings_set.all()
```

That will have the rating field, plus the `book` ForeignKey to get the Book.

Comment: ok. Thanks.How can I combine this two datasets?
I want a record with book + rating. Like in a join statement.

Comment: Django doesn't do that, because then you'd be breaking the object mapping. But there's no need: you can do `select_related('book')` to fetch the associated Books automatically, but the point is to stick to the objects: you have a BookRating, and the `book` field gives you access to the `Book` object.